# visual studio Firebase onDataChange

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I recently started learning to use FireBase in Visual Studio (C #)
My question is if it is possible to implement a function like OnDataChange like there is in Android Studio in order to monitor live changes in my database
Thank you all.

Comment: What type of C# application is this? Console, WinForms, WPF, Blazor, ASP.Net MVC, something else? Visual Studio is just a tool you use to _write_ the source code, just like Notepad.